# How do I enable local infile server side?

Tags: python, mysql

Firstly, I am new to Stack Overflow so appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my question asking in addition to any potential solutions.

I am using MySQL and Python (with Pycharm IDE) and I need to load data from a csv file into a table in a database I already created using MySQL Workbench (I am not using the Workbench import tool because it's too slow and I will need to do this from Pycharm in the future anyway).

I can connect to my database successfully from PyCharm and view the tables etc. I am then using the following to try and load the data from my CSV file -

```
mycursor = db.cursor()
query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file path' INTO TABLE scores FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ID, Date, Score)"
mycursor.execute(query)
```

I received an error when I did this and saw from another question on Stack Overflow that I needed to enable the 'local_infile' setting so I did that (I can see it's turned on).

However, I am still getting the error below when I try to import my data and from reading on Stock Overflow I believe this is because I also need to enable 'local_infile' on the server side but am unsure how to do this?

The error I am now getting when I try to load my data is as follows -

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError:
>
> 3948 (42000): Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

Comment: Did you add `allow_local_infile=True` to the connect call? Or did you enable it in the server settings?

Comment: You must set [`local_infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile) global variable (by `SET GLOBAL` or in server's *my.ini*) for to enable `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` on the server side...

Comment: ... and you must specify [`--local-infile`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_local-infile) and [`--load-data-local-dir`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_load-data-local-dir) in client's command line or according parameters in [mysql] section of *my.ini* used by your client or set your connection software accordingly.

Comment: local_infile is set to ON. I am now trying to upload from the MySQL command line client and I get the error "ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access." I found the my.ini file and added local-infile = 1 below the [mysqld] bit and I have also tried uploading the files from the hidden "Uploads" folder but still get this error